# Remove last digit from input type="tel" in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have full dialpad code .

Clear button clear all text from dialpad window. but i want to delete only last digit which i dial from dialpad.

language only javascript,jquery and html.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML, JS please

Comment: @BrentBoden and do not forget jQuery /s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function del(){
  var num=document.getElementById('num').value;
  num = num.substr(0, num.length - 1);
  document.getElementById('num').value=num;
}
function isValid(a){
  if(!(/^[0-9]+$/.test(a.value))){
    a.focus();
    console.clear();
    console.log("Please enter number");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" onblur="isValid(this);" id="num" /><button onclick="del();">Del</button>
```

**jQuery** - as per requested

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('button').on('click',function(){
    $('#num').val($('#num').val().substr(0,$('#num').val().length-1));
  });
});

//optional so not converted to jQuery
function isValid(a){
  if(!(/^[0-9]+$/.test(a.value))){
    a.focus();
    console.clear();
    console.log("Please enter number");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" onblur="isValid(this);" id="num" /><button>Del</button>
```

Comment: Is this work for type="tel" too?

Comment: yes. it will work

Comment: Ok thank you. @Sagar

Comment: u r welcome. But instead of saying thanks, marking as answer will help future visitors. @SuhaniMendapara

Comment: a little change has been made to improve performance. you can check it in answer

Comment: yeah i made it.

Comment: can you give me a code if it is in jquery ?? from your code i catch this much but substr is not working here.

Comment: function clearPhoneNumber() {
   
        var num = window.numberDisplayEl.val();
        console.log(num);
        num = num.substr(0, num.length - 1);
        window.numberDisplayEl.val(num);
        console.log(num);
    };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136541/discussion-between-suhani-mendapara-and-sagar-v).